# Superpowered plugin with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, installation, configure, superpowered

May I have a step-by-step tutorial/instructions about how to install superpowered plugin on Android Studio? 
I'm new on mobile developer world, and I have no ideia about how to do it. 
Thaks a lot and sorry about my English.

Comment: PS: I have both, Android Studio SDK and NDK instaled and working fine.

Comment: Sorry if my question is very poor, but on superpowered, this site is mentioned as a superpowered help place. I'm just asking for a startpoint to learn how to install it.

Answer (score 5):

Superpowered is not a plugin, it is a library.

First you need to know [**JNI**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) because android is mainly programed in Java and Superpowered is in C++, so you are going to need the JNI interface (is not really complex but you need your time to learn it)

Few months ago Superpowered was linked with the experimental gradle plugin, and it  was very easy to link Superpowered with your project, but now [**CMake**](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html) is the "official" mechanism for compile C++ in Android Studio so for new user is a little bit harder, but also is not really complex, so you need to know a little bit of CMake to link superpowered with your project, here are some [**info**](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html?hl=es-419)

and also watch the [**examples**](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/tree/master/Examples_Android) of Superpowered for Android, there it comes how to link it, is a really good start.

then when you have those 2 elements you can start using Superpowered.

it looks complicated but it worth it.